# How to make a user access only the website of a Odoo application

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-website

I am making a website with Odoo website module, and I want to create a login for my clients. I don't know the best practice for doing this.

My first thought was to consider my clients as new users with restricted access, but this way I can't prevent the users for entering the Odoo. My other thought was to extend the `res_partner` object and add a custom login/password for them, but this way I don't know how I can handle session management, authorization with them.

What is the best way to do it? Is there a way to use Odoo authentication and avoid my clients to leave the website and enter the Odoo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the new user in odoo, set the user access under Applications to nothing, this way the user dosen't have access to any application and when they login by default they'll be redirected to odoo website and won't get to the backend.

[image]

Make sure you also check the portal option.

Comment: Much simpler then I thought. Can I create this user via API?

Comment: yes you can with `xmlprc` or `jsonrpc`. xmlrpc is in the docs check out https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html